# Create a view with sum total across two tables grouped by date (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, view, grouping

I currently have a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.audit 
WITH schemabinding 
AS
    SELECT 
       CONVERT(date, DateAdded) AS dt, 
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS cnt
    FROM 
       dbo.Table1
    GROUP BY 
       CONVERT(date, DateAdded)
```

Which returns:

```
dt          cnt
-----------------
3/13/2015   5000
3/12/2015   1324
```

I'm trying to get a sum total count from both tables grouped by date into a single view. Is this possible?

i.e.

```
    Table 1                  Table 2
dt          cnt     |     dt          cnt
3/13/2015   5000    |     3/13/2015   1000
3/12/2015   1324    |     3/12/2015   1

To:

    View 1
dt          cnt
3/13/2015   6000
3/12/2015   1325
```

It would be nice to keep this in a single view. As it's just a running total of how many new items got added. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are two views and depending on *relationship* between these two views (based on values from `dt` columns: `View1.dt` and `View2.dt`) you could use a `INNER`/`LEFT`/`RIGHT` or `FULL JOIN` thus:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(v1.dt, v2.dt) AS dt, ISNULL(v1.cnt, 0) + ISNULL(v2.cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM    dbo.View1 v1 /*INNER/LEFT/RIGHT*/ FULL JOIN dbo.View2 v2 ON v1.dt = v2.dt
```

I've used `FULL JOIN` because I assumed that there are values in `View1.dt` column that doesn't exist in `View2.dt` column and also there are values in `View2.dt` column that doesn't exist in `View1.dt`. More, some `dt` values could exist in both columns(views).

Note: I assume that second view has the same definition but it uses `Table2` as data source: `FROM dbo.Table2`.

Comment: As I could not fully get the other solutions below working I decided to go this route with two views, I however did have to add a hint "WITH (NOEXPAND)" because the query was extremely slow without it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I saw that view is defined with SCHEMABINDING but I didn't see (within question) any reference to indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is such that there can be days missing from the tables it's easier to handle the dates by creating a table of dates (one row per day) so that you can join the tables using it, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.audit WITH schemabinding AS
select
  Dates.Date as dt,
  count_big(Table1.date) as ct_1,
  count_big(Table2.date) as ct_2
from
  Dates
  left outer join Table1 on convert(date, Table1.Date) = Dates.Date 
  left outer join Table2 on convert(date, Table2.Date) = Dates.Date
group by
  Dates.Date
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf116/3

If the tables are huge there might be some problems with performance because SQL Server isn't going to use index for the dates because there is a conversion to date -- and this is in case you have a where clause on the view. If you need something like that an inline table value function might work better because then you can have variables for the date ranges.

Comment: Another small datapoint to consider that might adjust your approach is I do not care about historical records, I only ever lookup the current date's (CURDATE()) totals... So I wonder if there is a better way with that in mind then maintaining a 3rd table of just dates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.audit WITH schemabinding AS
SELECT CONVERT(Table1.date,DateAdded) AS Table1_dt, 
       COUNT_BIG(Table1.*) AS Table1_cnt,
       CONVERT(Table1.date,DateAdded) AS Table2_dt, 
       COUNT_BIG(Table2.*) AS Table2_cnt
FROM dbo.Table1 INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 ON(Table1.date = Table2.Date)
GROUP BY CONVERT(Table1,DateAdded)
```

This solution assumes the same column names in both tables and also the same dates to be selected.